# index out of range error on python multiple choice

Tags: python

**File name:** Question.py

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt 
        self.answer = answer
```

**File name** student.py

```
from Question import Question 

This is my code 
question_prompts = [
    'what color are apples?\n(a) red\n(b) purple\n(c) orange\n\n'
    'what color are bananas?\n(a) teal\n(b) black\n(c) yellow\n\n'
    'what color are oranges?\n(a) white\n(b) orange\n(c) red\n\n'
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], 'a'),
    Question(question_prompts[1], 'c'),
    Question(question_prompts[2], 'b'),
]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print('you got ' + str(score) + '/' + str(len(questions)) + 'correct')

run_test(questions)
```

**error**

line 11, in 
Question(question_prompts[1], 'c'),
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: the problem is that `question_prompts` has only 1 element so `question_prompts[1]` raises an IndexError. The different questions should be separated by a comma

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm pretty sure you were even *following the same tutorial* as in the linked duplicate. Hint: look closely at how `questions` is defined. What is the last thing you see on each line? A comma (`,`), right? What is the purpose of that? Now, look closely at `question_prompts`. Should it have those too? Why or why not? Does it?

Comment: Why did four different people answer for a common typo?

Answer (score -1):

You should use commas to separate your strings. Python concatenates successive strings into one automatically.

Use:

```
question_prompts = [
    'what color are apples?\n(a) red\n(b) purple\n(c) orange\n\n',
    'what color are bananas?\n(a) teal\n(b) black\n(c) yellow\n\n',
    'what color are oranges?\n(a) white\n(b) orange\n(c) red\n\n'
]
```

Your code without commas:

```
question_prompts = [
    'what color are apples?\n(a) red\n(b) purple\n(c) orange\n\n'
    'what color are bananas?\n(a) teal\n(b) black\n(c) yellow\n\n'
    'what color are oranges?\n(a) white\n(b) orange\n(c) red\n\n'
]
```

Was equivalent to:

```
question_prompts = [
    'what color are apples?\n(a) red\n(b) purple\n(c) orange\n\nwhat color are bananas?\n(a) teal\n(b) black\n(c) yellow\n\nwhat color are oranges?\n(a) white\n(b) orange\n(c) red\n\n'
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding commas to separate the different items in your list.  Without the commas Python will just concatenate all of the strings into one.

For example:

```
>>> no_commas = ['a' 'b' 'c']
>>> print(no_commas)
['abc']
>>> commas = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print(commas)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

You are seeing an index out of range error because your list ends up only having one item instead of three (and thus only goes up to index 0).

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You should add comma between each element of questions. (line 4~6)

```
question_prompts = [
    'what color are apples?\n(a) red\n(b) purple\n(c) orange\n\n',
    'what color are bananas?\n(a) teal\n(b) black\n(c) yellow\n\n',
    'what color are oranges?\n(a) white\n(b) orange\n(c) red\n\n'
]
```

If you don't add comma between multiple string, then python will interpret as single concatenated string.